# Google Sheets Formula - Query multiple rows and cols into one cell on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

The mail merge app I am using to generate invoices will only read and send 1 row per email, therefore, in generating an invoice, i need to dynamically (as the number of line items will be unknown) get line items from the *invoice items* table onto the *invoice* table, and place the result onto the invoice table row that will be sent.

[image]

How can this be done using a formula and not a script? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a test sheet for your convenience: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2f877BJl1mWDGbyicAiCnFiTNyLrgvjKSLBQ03Suak/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: i had started to play around with this idea: =join(CHAR(10),QUERY('Invoice Items'!B2:N, "select H where C = '"&B7&"' order by D,B")), but then soon realized that "JOIN" being used in this context will only let you query one column, and not multiple columns. So back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised answer. In cell A1 of Invoices Sheet put the formula below and copy it down however many row you may need (number of possible Items). If Items are blank, the copied down cell will be blank. Then in B1 of the Invoices Sheet put the next formula to consolidate in one cell.

```
=if('Invoice Items Sheet'!$A2<>"",(concatenate('Invoice Items Sheet'!$A2,"-",'Invoice Items Sheet'!$B2,"-",text('Invoice Items Sheet'!$C2,"$0.00"),"-",text('Invoice Items Sheet'!$D2,"$0.00"),char(10))),"")

=Concatenate(A:A)
```

Just another idea to make your invoice more readable look at:

```
=if('Invoice Items Sheet'!$A2<>"",(concatenate('Invoice Items Sheet'!$A2,"  ",'Invoice Items Sheet'!$B2," x ",text('Invoice Items Sheet'!$C2,"$0.00")," = ",text('Invoice Items Sheet'!$D2,"$0.00"),char(10))),"")
```

Comment: Interesting... while you are technically correct per the way i worded the question, the challenge lies in the fact that the number of items will be unknown, so to do a manual concatenate wouldn't fit the real world scenario, i need to figure out how to get your example to work with a dynamic loop of some sort, as the number of items will be different and unknown from invoice to invoice. But your example i think is steering my in the right direction. I will modify the question to clarify this.

Comment: Wow brother, that did it! How do you guys wrap your minds around this stuff!